# Can you get the length of a list of adjacent points in an adjacency list in Python?

Tags: python, list

I'd like to find a convenient way to get the length of a list in an adjacency list.

Creating an empty list and appending a list from the adjacency list into it doesn't work well.

The original code without creating an empty list within the function:

```
def road_map(point_map, n):
    criteria_met = 0
    p = 0
    for p in point_map:
        points = len(point_map[p])
        for i in point_map[p]:
            if len(point_map[p]) >= n:
                criteria_met += 1
        p += 1
    return criteria_met
```

For example:
there's a train station (0), an airport (1), an office tower (2) and a hotel (3) in a certain part of a town, as in:

```
town_points = [[1, 3], [0, 2], [1], [0]]
```

and we want:

```
print(road_map(town_points, 2))
```

to find areas connected to at least 2 other buildings specified.

This happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/untitled1/roadmap.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(road_map(town_points, 2))
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/untitled1/roadmap.py", line 5, in road_map
    points = len(point_map[p])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

It might seem convenient and more conventional to use sub-functions to grab the list from the adjacency list, but I'm doubting its usefulness.

Comment: `points = len(p)` should suffice to get the number of items in the sublist but not sure what result you're aiming to achieve. Edit your question and describe what result you expect.

Comment: I didn't realize that until now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down your problem:

1. You want to find the length of each list in adjacency list
2. You want to count the number of lists with length >= 2

First, let's take a look at the `road_map` function you provided. The lines `p=0` and `p+=1` isn't needed, since the loop `for p in point_map:` will replace the `p` with elements of `point_map` list. Hence, the function can be simplified into:

```
def road_map(point_map, n):
    criteria_met = 0
    for p in point_map:
        points = len(point_map[p])
        for i in point_map[p]:
            if len(point_map[p]) >= n:
                criteria_met += 1
    return criteria_met
```

However, this will still yield `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list`. There are several problems in this code, but let's focus on the cause of the error. The loop `for p in point_map` means in each iteration, `p` is an element of `point_map`. In your example, in the first iteration, `p` holds the value `[1,3]`, and then in the next iteration, `[0,2]`, and so on.

A python list can only be indexed with an integer and not another list. When we access `point_map[p]` in the first iteration, we're using `p` which is a list `[1,3]` as the index.

Since `p` is already the list of adjacent nodes in each iteration, we can use `len(p)` to know the number of adjacent nodes of each node. Hence, the code to find areas connected to at least 2 other buildings specified can be written as:

```
def road_map(point_map, n):
    criteria_met = 0
    for p in point_map:
        if len(p) >= n:
            criteria_met += 1
    return criteria_met
```

or, in a far more compact version:

```
def road_map(point_map, n):
    return len([l for l in point_map if len(l)>=n])
```

In this code `[l for l in point_map if len(l)>=n]` iterates through every single element `l` of `point_map`, which in this case is always a list. Then, it filters out every `l` that does not meet the criterion `len(l)>=n`. After that, we use `len([l for l in point_map if len(l)>=n])` to calculate the length of the resulting list.

Comment: Well, it worked. Thanks. I'm still quite new to all this but seems like the methods of getting the length of a list from the graph adjacency list differs significantly from getting the length of a standalone list.